# Write a Non-equidistant dfs0

Tags: python, mikeio

I know how to create a equidistant dfs0.

```
from mikeio import Dfs0
data = [np.random.random([100])]
dfs = Dfs0()
dfs.write('simple.dfs0', data, start_time=datetime(2017, 1, 1), dt=60)
```

But how do I create a non-equidistant file, e.g. with samples taken irregularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your non-equidistant data in a pandas dataframe, you can export it to dfs0.

The index of the dataframe must be a `DatetimeIndex`.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from mikeio import Dfs0

df = pd.read_csv("my_sample_data.csv", parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
df.to_dfs0("my_sample_data.dfs0")
```